# Django - How to pull data that has been added to the SQLite database on a different branch

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm very new to Django so please be patient with me and sorry if it is a dumb question. I am working with a partner on a Django project with a Django admin and we are using SQLite for our database. We both work on our own branches and have been each putting in lookup table values and dummy data.

How can I pull the data that my partner has been adding so I can see it on my own branch? The SQLite file is not in gitignore. For some reason though even when he pushes his changes to master and I pull the changes onto my own branch, I can't see the data he has put in my own branch and can only see it when switching over to the master branch or his branch.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did your partner pushed DB file to master branch?
Did you pull and rebase master?
It not Django's problem, it belong to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of django development.

Since you're sharing your SQLite file over git, you should be able to *see* someone else changes.

Try these steps to troubleshoot why you're not seeing them

1. Make sure you're telling django the correct db file to use.
   in `settings.py`

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'database_you_want_to_use.db',
    }
}
```

2. Make sure the DB you pulled actually has the data you're looking for in it. If you're using PyCharm, there's a [built-in Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/database-tool-window.html) for seeing the schema and records. There's also a [stand-alone viewer for sqlite files](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Since you're new to django, you might not know that's there's *much* easier ways out there for handling a database that multiple developers need to interact with.

Since you're using sqlite, your options are limited. However, [django has a nice built in tool](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models) for auto-populating your database with a bunch of records you define in a file. That way, instead of sharing a database over git (which is pretty bad practice), you can share a script that when run, will fill both your databases with the same records.

This also eliminates the need to add records by hand with django-admin.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a great response!

Comment: @KathyTran No problem! Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the solution if you found it helpful!